# AttributeError: 'OpenpyxlWriter' object has no setter when setting writer.book

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to extract data from an Excel file using openpyxl and pandas. 
 

The code follows these steps;

1. asks the user to input a date in the format `'ddmmyyhhmm'`,
2. loads the corresponding Excel file,
3. tries to append data to an existing worksheet using `pd.ExcelWriter`.

However unfortunately I encounter the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Anto\Daily Work\Programming\py\All Reservoir.py", line 217, in <module>
    main()
  File "d:\Anto\Daily Work\Programming\py\All Reservoir.py", line 210, in main
    extract_data_from_excel()
  File "d:\Anto\Daily Work\Programming\py\All Reservoir.py", line 59, in extract_data_from_excel
    writer.book = book
  AttributeError: property 'book' of 'OpenpyxlWriter' object has no setter
```

**Steps to Reproduce**:

1. Run the script.
2. Enter the date in the format `'ddmmyyhhmm'` (e.g., 02082023_0000).

**Expected Behavior**:
I expect the script to load the Excel file, append data to the existing worksheet, and save the changes.

**Code Snippet**:

```
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'D:\Anto\Daily Work\Daily Reservoir Level\August\Plotting\Excel\{}.xlsx'.format(my_list[j], data_only=True))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'D:\Anto\Daily Work\Daily Reservoir Level\August\Plotting\Excel\{}.xlsx'.format(my_list[j]),engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay')
writer.book = book
```

**Additional Information**:

Python version: 3.11.4
pandas version: 2.0.3
openpyxl version: 3.1.2

This code worked in python 3.11 but now returning the error,

```
def main():
    continue_extraction = True
    while continue_extraction:
        extract_data_from_excel()
        choice = input("Do you want to continue? (y/n): ")
        if choice.lower() != 'y':
            continue_extraction = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(), when running second time , at first getting output
```

Comment: Where is _the script_ you talk about?

Comment: Thanks for you reply the error is resolved , as i mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'D:\Anto\Daily Work\Reserviour\July\Plotting\Excel\{}.xlsx'.format(my_list[j], data_only=True))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'D:\Anto\Daily Work\Reserviour\July\Plotting\Excel\{}.xlsx'.format(my_list[j]),engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay')
writer.book = book
sheet = book['Sheet1']
last_row = len(sheet['B'])
print(last_row)
this part of code made the error which is not compatible with latest version of python, I changed it to 
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path, data_only=True)
with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
sheet = book['Sheet1']
last_row = len(sheet['B'])
print(last_row)
and removed #writer.save() from the code now its working, tha
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i faced similar issue after python version upgrade to 3.11.5
fixed with below change with using book

Before

```
        book = load_workbook(excel_template,data_only=True)      
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_template, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay')       
        writer.book = book
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False, header=False)
        writer.save()
```

After

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_template, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:            
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False, header=False)        
            #writer.save()
```